# ArcGIS for Server 10.2.1 cache scale greyed out in Service Editor and not all scales available in Manage Map Server Cache Tiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, cache

I am using ArcInfo desktop 10.2.1, with an admin connection to ArcGIS for Server Standard 10.2.1

I have used the "Create Map Server Cache" tool in ArcToolbox to prepare all the underlying structure for the cache of an existing un-cached basemap service.

I've used a predefined tiling scheme, which tells it to generate cache tiles at 3 scales - 1:8000, 1:5000, 1:2000.

I've set the tile cache format the "PNG" and the Storage format to "Compact".

This tool runs without any problems.

The problem comes when I come to actually generate the cache using the "Manage Map Server Cache Tiles" tool from the toolbox.

Only 2 of my 3 scales are visible in the "Scales" box.

[image]

In Catalog, if I right click on my service > Service Properties > Caching, the slider shows the full extent of the 3 scales I want to cache at.

[image]

If I click on the Advanced Settings tab, I can see the 3 scales, however one of them is greyed out.  This is the one that's missing from the "Managae Map Server Cache Tiles" tool.

[image]

Is this a bug in the software? Or is there something I have missed?
I've also tried it with ArcInfo 10.1 and I get the same problem.

Is there a limit to the number of tiles a single cache scale can hold? Or a size limit?

If this is a bug, is there a workaround?

Comment: Check the cache directory on the server to see if it's created 3 folders for the 3 scales.

Comment: There are only 2 folders.

Comment: In the cache directory, there should be a file called `conf.xml` - check that file to see if all three layers are listed in the LOD category. Usually when a layer is greyed out like that, you've opted to not cache that scale somewhere.

Comment: Also in the Advanced Settings screen from your last screenshot, there should be `Minimum cached scale` and `Maximum cached scale` right below where you cropped the image. Be sure 2000 is included in the `Maximum cached scale` dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mintx suggested in comments I would gess as well that this can be done by the setting of the Min and Max cache scale on Advanced Caching Properties. Once I solved similar problem with this setting.

[image]